# Java program does not show as stopped on console after exit

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a self-updating java app. This app downloads a new version of it, launches the new version after the download using the `ProcessBuilder` class and tells the JVM to delete the old version once the JVM quits. The code for the launch is as follows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = null;
if (deleteOldVersion) {
    try {
        String path = UpdateChecker.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
        log.getLogger().info("The following file will be deleted, once the JVM exits: " + decodedPath);
        (new File(decodedPath)).deleteOnExit();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "An error occurred", e);
    }
}

log.getLogger().info("Launching new version using command: java -jar " + destFolder + File.separator + destFilename);
pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", destFolder + File.separator + destFilename).inheritIO();
pb.start();
System.exit(0);
```

The new process starts as it should and it inherits standard out and in as it should too, but when I exit the new version of the app, the command line never shows the process as finished:
[image: console image after shutdown]

There are no threads left that are running and for some strange reason, I can't reproduce the behaviour in eclipse or when I launch the new version normally.

What is going wrong here? I know that leaving out `.inheritIO()` would do the trick but I really want to use the same standard in and out with the new version.

Comment: Can you describe in a bit more detail what the expected behavior is? The *subprocess* that you're starting will be killed when you call `System.exit(0)` in your main process.

Comment: Hi, I don't mind if the process of the "old version" runs in the background. Only when the new Version (the subprocess) exits, I want everything to exit. `System.exit(0)` apparently does not kill the sub process as it runs and is never killed :)